For Each Loop over an array of sheets - Subscripts out of range error
I have a sub, LoopThroughLocations, that loops through seven sheets (one for each of our locations) in my workbook and adds borders to the range with data (the size of the range changes week to week).
The seven sheets are created by a pervious sub which filtered the data by location and created a separate set for each location. This sub has been working perfectly of the past year... until today when it turned out that the input data had no data for our Chicago location and as such did not create a "CHICAGO" sheet (only six locations had data this week).
Now the For Each loop produces a "Subscript output to Range" error when it gets to "CHICAGO" in the array.
Is there any way to check for the existence of a sheet before trying to loop through it?
Or maybe I should create the array in the previous sub, but I'm not sure how to pass it.
Any help will be much apprciated.

    Dim Locations As Variant
    Dim Loc As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Locations = Array("ATLANTA", "BOSTON", "CHICAGO", "LASVEGAS", "LOSANGELES", "NEWORLEANS", "NASHVILLE")
    
    For Each Loc In Locations
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Loc)
        Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  ' Last row of source worksheet
        
        ws.Range("A" & Lastrow & ":FO" & Lastrow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    Next Loc

End Sub~~~


You can see how to check for an existing sheet here
